# Javascript files are automatically changed by eslintrc.json

Tags: javascript, coding-style, refactoring, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb

In visual studio 2015 we have a solution with c# and javascript files. For the javascript files, we use a .eslintrc.json file for code conventions. However, everytime I build the solution, these files are automatically changed to the settings in this .eslintrc.json (for example change double quotes to single quotes). Is there a way to prevent it from automatically refactore everyting, but instead give warnings or something?

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "semi": [ "warn", "always" ],
    "max-len": [ "warn", 200 ],
    "arrow-body-style": [ "error", "as-needed" ],
    "indent": [
      "warn",
      2,
      { "SwitchCase": 1 }
    ],
    "no-param-reassign": [
      "error",
      { "props": true }
    ],
    "space-before-function-paren": [
      "error",
      {
        "anonymous": "never",
        "named": "never",
        "asyncArrow": "ignore"
      }
    ],
    "eqeqeq": "warn",
    "no-restricted-syntax": "warn",
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "class-methods-use-this": 0,
    "no-plusplus": 0,
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "no-confusing-arrow": 0,
    "no-mixed-operators": 0,
    "func-names": 0,
    "no-console": 0,
    "no-use-before-define": 0,
    "comma-dangle": 0,
    "guard-for-in": 0,
    "no-extend-native": 0,
    "no-empty": 0
  },
  "globals": {
    "Utils": false,
    "location": false,
    "fetch": false,
    "webApi": false,
    "$": false,
    "window": false,
    "document": false,
    "console": false,
    "GeoSettings": false,
    "localStorage": false,
    "sessionStorage": false,
    "BPlanInteractions": false,
    "navigator": false,
    "saveAs": false,
    "HTMLCanvasElement": false,
    "atob": false,
    "Blob": false
  }
}
```

I thought maybe it is something defined in "airbnb-base" that it extends, but I couldn't find anything there either.

Thanks!

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: Visual studio 2015